# continuing same Audio while changing scene - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

So I wanted to continue the same music from the same time while changing from the main menu to a new scene. so I did this:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public AudioSource bgm;
    
        void Update()
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(bgm);
        }
    }
```

this works fine. but when I come back to the main menu the same music starts playing twice at the same time. So what can I do so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: Lookup singletons

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the Update function including the "DontDestroyOnLoad(bgm)" Line
2. Remove the variable named bgm
3. Create a static instance variable of the class in the class itself and use it to check whether you should destroy it or not. Example:

   private static AudioManager audioManager;

   private void Awake() {
   DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);

   ```
    if (audioManager == null) {
        audioManager = this;
    } else {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
   ```

   }